# PHP поиск файлов по Русскому имени

Tags: php, glob

У меня есть код, он отлично работает, но только если имена файлов написаны по Английски.
Файлы, имена которых написаны на Русском он просто не видит.
Как можно изменить данный код, чтобы он видел Русскоязычные файлы?

```
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {$text = $_POST['text']; 
$dir = __DIR__ . '/docs';
$files = array();
$wli = 0;
$wlstr = '';
foreach(glob($dir . '/'.$text.'*.*') as $file) {
    $wli++;
    $files[] = basename($file); 
    $wlstr .= '<p class="wlp">'.$wli.'. '.basename($file).'<span class="wlp2">'.basename($file).'</span>'.'</p>';
} 
echo $wlstr;
}
```

Comment: а зачем вам вообще glob? `DirectoryIterator` же есть

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос функцией:

```
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {$text = $_POST['text']; 
$wli = 0;
$wlstr = '';

$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__). '/docs');
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    
    $fis = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    $fis2 = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $fis);
    
    $pos = strstr($fis2,$text);
    if ($pos != '')
    {
        $wli++;
        $wlstr .= '<p class="wlp">'.$wli.'. '.$fis2.'<span    class="wlp2">'.$fis2.'</span>'.'</p>';
    }
}
    echo $wlstr;
}
```